# Custom ComboBox layout

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Im trying to make a custom selector that fills the whole page and looks like this (each box represents different selection):

[image: preview]
The elements have to be loaded from xml, allways 3 per row, infinite amount of rows possible (based on xml file).

So far i have gotten to building custom DataTemplate with this example:
[example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/47923/Using-a-different-DataTemple-when-a-WPF-ComboBox-i)

But i have no idea how to approach making selection show fullscreen with multiple rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a fixed number of columns you can use an `ItemsControl` or a `ListBox` using a `UniformGrid` as the `ItemPanel` used to lay out the items

Sample Xaml Template

```xml
<ListBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding MyElementsLoadedFromXml}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock FontSize="26"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding AFieldInMyXmlElement}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="3" IsItemsHost="True" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

It should look like this by default:

[image: Visual Demo]

The `IsItemsHost="True"` is optional when not using a scrollviewer but as it is meant to be used in this use case I think it is better to use it here anyway

Edit: I forgot it was about ComboBox but as they behave really close to each other, if you replace ListBox by ComboBox you get what I think is your expected result : [image: ComboBox Sample Visual]

Comment: Great answer, very helpfull ! :) Also in my example i see it will be even better to switch to ListBox. Beeing new was not aware i can make it look like that. Thanks